# JPA is creating a VARCHAR column for my INT field

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

everyone,

Currently I'm trying to create a table according to my class specification and I'm getting an error which is "Incorrect column specifier for column 'ID'". This is due to my ID field being a VARCHAR(255) and having AUTO_INCREMENT, as you can see in the following error:

```
Error executing: CREATE TABLE gameuserstate (ID VARCHAR(255) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADDRESS VARCHAR(255), CITY VARCHAR(255), DOCUMENTID VARCHAR(255), FBUSERID VARCHAR(255), IDENTIFIER VARCHAR(255), LASTNAME VARCHAR(255), NAME VARCHAR(255), PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), STATE VARCHAR(255), USERSTATE LONGTEXT, USERID VARCHAR(255), ZIPCODE VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

The problem is: my class' ID field type is INT!
How is it possible that JPA is using a VARCHAR(255) field to represent an int?

This is my entity class:

```
@Table(name = "gameuserstate")
@Cacheable(false)
@Entity
public class JpaGameUserState {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String userid;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private JpaAccount account;

    @Column
    private String fbUserId;

    @Column
    private String identifier;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String documentId;

    @Column
    private String state;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @Column
    private String zipcode;

    // this will hold old userstate object format
    @Lob
    @Column
    private String userState;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public JpaAccount getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(JpaAccount account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public String getFbUserId() {
        return fbUserId;
    }

    public void setFbUserId(String fbUserId) {
        this.fbUserId = fbUserId;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getUserState() {
        return userState;
    }

    public void setUserState(String userState) {
        this.userState = userState;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `Long ` as a `id` and then try to create the db table

Comment: I already did it, the same thing happened.

Comment: You have no getter and setter for your id field

Comment: @lucasfcosta you have tried a `Long` or a `long` as id type?

Comment: @Jens both
And I've just tried with getters and setters and the same thing happened.

Comment: Try long primitive type is it working or not??

Comment: why do you have primaryJoinColumn that column account is primary key and that is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [All types of @Generated ] [1]

[1] http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: Yes I did, and I've tried them all.
.AUTO, for example, works, but the ID field is still VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

if you are not providing the sequence definition to the entity the JPA won't apply auto_increment but it will apply the sequence for assigning new ids for the new inserted rows so you should use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`
like this

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

Comment: I have also tried this and the same thing still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Today I've discovered the answer for this.

The problem was that I was using the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation at the account attribute. Removing it made everything work as expected.